# xslt named template number always going into xsl:otherwise block

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I've a date suffix function that adds st, nd, rd, th suffix with a date

```
<xsl:template name="date_suffix">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$date &gt; 10 and $date &lt; 14">th</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 1">st</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 2">nd</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 3">rd</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am calling it in this way

```
<xsl:template match="date">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:call-template name="date_suffix">
        <xsl:with-param name="date" seelect="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

This is my XAML Fragment

```
    <dob>
        <date>23</date>
        <month>Dec</month>
        <year>1987</year>
    </dob>
```

The problem is I see `23th` Whereas I expect `23rd`. This `choose`, `when` works fine when I use it directly inside `<xsl:template match="date">` block but doesn't when when called as named template

Comment: For diagnostics, use xsl:message to display the value of $date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `seelect` to `select`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not restricted to XSL Version 1.0, it might be helpful to use a function with strongly typed parameters instead of a named template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xyz="urn:mystuff"
version="2.0">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="date">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:value-of select="xyz:date_suffix(.)" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:function name="xyz:date_suffix" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="date" as="xs:integer"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 1">st</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 2">nd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="($date mod 10) = 3">rd</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>th</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```